# Return value by mysql_query for insert query

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql c api, I want to know that, is there any way so that I will come to know my insert query failed because I tried to insert duplicate value for primary key. I know I can retrieve existing entries and compare it with value which I want to insert but it will be better if I get to know it by return value of mysql_query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/mysql_query everything is there.

Comment: have a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-error.html ( if query is false, then have a look into mysql_error() )